# User registration verification with their device IMEI/ESN?

Tags: android, validation

I am working on an application that will validate users with their device IMEI/ESN number and keep records of all previous IMEI/ESN if user changes device, is there any useful way. I already get device IMEI/ESN but how I use it for user verification?

Alternative Question: If it is not possible then how i'll send 4 digit code(like viber) on user number after register into application?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

> Alternative Question: If it is not possible then how i'll send 4 digit
>   code(like viber) on user number after register into application ?

You can generate  unique alpha-numeric strings from server  side and Map as per your requirement .

if you are using java server then following code would help

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomString
{

  private static final char[] symbols = new char[36];

  static {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; ++idx)
      symbols[idx] = (char) ('0' + idx);
    for (int idx = 10; idx < 36; ++idx)
      symbols[idx] = (char) ('a' + idx - 10);
  }

  private final Random random = new Random();

  private final char[] buf;

  public RandomString(int length)
  {
    if (length < 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("length < 1: " + length);
    buf = new char[length];
  }

  public String nextString()
  {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < buf.length; ++idx) 
      buf[idx] = symbols[random.nextInt(symbols.length)];
    return new String(buf);
  }
```

}

and if you server language is PHP then you can do something like this using MD%

```
md5(uniqid(rand(), true))
```

however the length of the input of the md5 function is greater than length of its output and according to the [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) the collision is guaranteed so uniqueness is not guarantee in that case

After that you need to MAP those key and value using web service